# Unrecognized pref_type 0 for NullProfileSettings pref name default_non_connection_tab

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

I get the error

"error": {
      "message": "SETTINGS: Unrecognized pref_type 0 for NullProfileSettings pref name default_non_connection_tab.",
      "type": "Exception"
}

when trying to view this feed

https://graph.facebook.com/10150331381804198/feed?access_token=[correct access token]

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this one, I have a similar situation where one site is working ok and another isn't. Exactly the same method used to retrieve the feed, simply different group ids

Answer (score 0):

I think facebook Open Graph still not support any connections(ex. feed, posts).
Because probably it's now Beta season.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect object id (e.g. page, user, ...)